# How to update data in a mysql linked server if another data from it matches the data from the local sql server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables, both locally:
tableA in SQL Server
userId, userNo (all nvchar)
tableB in linked MySQL
userid, userno (all nvchar)

I want to update userNo to userno if userId matches userid.

And create as a trigger in tableA so tableB gets updated once data coming.

Every query I tried to make gives me syntax error or something.

Please help, thanks heaps!

I have tried below

```
SELECT userId FROM tableA AS a

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL_LINKED,'SELECT userid FROM tableB') AS b

UPDATE OPENQUERY(MYSQL_LINKED, 'select userno from tableB')
SET userno = userNo
WHERE a = b
```

Updated according to @Patrick Hurst

```
UPDATE a
   SET a.userno = s._userNo
  FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL_LINKED, 'SELECT * FROM gameacc.logintable 
 WHERE userid = ''s._userId''') a
    INNER JOIN WORLDDB.GAME.USERINFO s
      ON a.userid = s._userId;
```

I ran the above code and it did went through no error, HOWEVER it said 'Affected Rows: 0', but I'm pretty sure both userid and _userId have data and can confirm they are identical, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use two different RDMS? It's going to be a lot more striaght forward for you, especially as a novice, if you can bring your data into a single instance and/or database.

Comment: i have to do this way since i turned off my remote connection in mssql, i have reasons... so im using mysql as a bridge to manipulate data for my program, so it doesn't have to connect to mssql directly.

Comment: That's a pretty poor design choice. I'd strongly suggest you pick one and stick with it. You're introducing all sorts of potential issues. If you don't want to use SQL Server then import your data into MySQL (using the linked server maybe?) or vice-versa.

Comment: @PatrickHurst i understand its not a best way to do but i have reasons... the reason why i can't use mssql directly is because one of my program can only use mssql and it has to use a certain user/pass with all privileges and those info are public on the Internet, which is also sadly i can't change. if i turn on remote connection for mssql and use it through my client program, it will be easier for me for sure but anyone knows my ip can easily get access to my mssql

Answer (score 1):

You can try this syntax:

```
UPDATE a
   SET <ColumnToUpdate> = <Value>
  FROM OPENQUERY(<YourLinkedServer>, 'SELECT * FROM <Database>.<Schema>.<Table> 
 WHERE <FilterColumn> = ''<FilterValue>''') a
    INNER JOIN <LocalDatabase>.<LocalSchema>.<LocalTable> s
      ON a.<RemoteColumnToMatchOn> = s.<LocalColumnToMatchOn>;
```

Replace the placeholders with your values.

It's probably best to use the WHERE clause to limit your update to a single row at first, to make sure the changes are what you expect.

Comment: thanks for answer so quickly! however i don't want to input any manual data as i want it to be excuted as a trigger automatically since data are already there.

Comment: Understood, but you can replace the `<ColumnToUpdate>` and `<Value>` with column names. Be sure to use the appropriate alias, though.

Comment: now thats the part im very confused of, how to use appropriate alias for my case for example? thank u so much!

Comment: You get to choose the alias. For example: `SELECT * FROM MyTable a` in this case `a` is the alias for the table.
In the example above the REMOTE table has been alias as `a` and the local table as `s`. To update the remote table we used `UPDATE a SET <ColumnName> = <Value>` to change this to use column names we might use `UPDATE a SET MyColumn = s.MyLocalColumn` which would cause the remote column MyColumn to be set to the value of the local column MyLocalColumn

Comment: I ran your code and it did went through no error, HOWEVER it said 'Affected Rows: 0', but I'm pretty sure both userid and _userId have data and can confirm they are identical, what should I do?

Comment: If you received that message you didn't have a match between the two tables. Change it to a select and review the results.